# MVC BULK PRINTING

Tags: model-view-controller, printing, bulk

Need some help or ideas.

I have a **view** where I get *a list of data*, for each object I have a **checkbox**. Now I also added a select all were the total is 900 - 1100 objects. I want to pass these values to another view(**Invoice Template** I have) when that view opens my print screen opens as well to print. Now my question is, can I get all the page to **print on ONE click** so my print preview must not have page to print 1/1 it must say 1000/1000

Is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just send my `object` to my **view** where I do a my `foreach` to add all the data. Using a large query string I added `maxQueryStringLength="32768"` and `maxQueryString="32768"` to my `web.config`

This allows me to print up-to **2000 sheets on one click**